# How can i create progress bar with border opacity?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I am trying to create the progress bar like the one native in Macosx + Chrome as the [picture shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CLZo.png). How can i create the border with opacity for several color?

```css
progress {
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

progress[value="1"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 1em 0 0 1em;
  background-color: #dc3545;
}

progress[value="2"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 1em 0 0 1em;
  background-color: #ffc107;
}

progress[value="3"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 1em 0 0 1em;
  background-color: #1178f7;
}

progress[value="4"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 1em 0 0 1em;
  background-color: #17a2b8;
}

progress[value="5"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: #28a745;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  /* style rules */
}
```

```html
<progress value="3" max="5">3 %</progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `border` property, you can change the color to an `rgba` one and from there change the last value in the set based on how opaque you want your border to be.
The below example is your `hex`, `#b2b2b2`, converted to an `rgba`, `rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.5)` with an opacity of 50%.

```
progress {
  border: 1px solid rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Change border property to `progress{}`does not help much. I need the way to opaque the border of  `-webkit-progress-value` so that its border overlaps the one of `progress{}` on the same line and is still opacity (like picture shown). Maybe it is not possible?